# How to use the OR in a conditional on Command Line

Tags: windows, cmd, command

I want to make this in Windows command  Line

```
IF ("A" == "A" OR "A" == "B" OR  "A" == "C") THEN
     .....
ELSE
    .....
```

how is the better way  thanks

Comment: what are the possible options?

Comment: i assume the above logic is just an example there must be variables yes?

Comment: Yes the really important is the OR operator not the variables

Comment: its a command script, it's fine.

Comment: The operator OR don't work

Comment: why don't you show your actual code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438511/if-or-if-in-a-windows-batch-file