# Else If not working, check folder name.

Tags: batch-file

I have this code which works perfectly,

```
    :process_video

FOR /F "delims=\" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
    SET a=%%i
    GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof

:found
echo Most recent video created: &echo. & echo."%a%"
if  /i "%a:~-3%"=="ESP" 
else if  /i "%a:~-3%"=="GBR" goto:next
cd %a%
for %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%~na-%a%%%~xa"
cd ..\
ren "%a%" "%a% - ESP"
echo.
echo ESP video has been processed
echo.
pause
exit /b

:next
echo.
echo.ESP Video already processed
echo.
pause

:exit
exit /b
```

However I would like to expand the check criteria not only just ESP, but other words.

I tried this, but with not luck:

```
if  /i "%a:~-3%"=="ESP", 
else if /i "%a:~-3%"=="GBR", 
else if/i "%a:~-3%"=="SPE" goto:next
```

ANd this

```
echo Most recent video created: &echo. & echo."%a%"
if /i "%a:~-3%"=="ESP" ( 
goto:next 
) else if /i "%a:~-3%"=="GBR" 
(
goto:next 
) else if /i "%a:~-3%"=="SPE"
(
goto:next
)
else
)
echo THis works 
)
```

I thought it would be an else if?

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Update:

```
:found
echo Most recent video created: &echo. & echo."%a%"
if /i "%a:~-3%"=="ESP" goto:next else goto:GBR
:GBR
if /i "%a:~-3%"=="GBR" goto:next else goto:SPE
:SPE
if /i "%a:~-3%"=="SPE" goto:next
```

This works, however, for me it is not clean, why is the else if not working,

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081735/how-to-use-if-else-structure-in-a-batch-file

Comment: @AndiMohr  Thanks Andi, but not joy. I tried it. But not joy. This is one of this first things I tried, looked up other posts.

Comment: Hm ok - did you see this post? Might be more useful as the top answer deals with FOR/DO loops: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8439069/1607446

Comment: @AndiMohr I shall give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @AndiMohr I found a solution, please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want an OR with the text then this will work.

```
for %%a in (ESP GBR SPE) do if  /i "%a:~-3%"=="%%a" goto:next
```

Here is a proof of concept

```
@echo off
set a=123456.GBR
for %%a in (ESP GBR SPE) do if  /i "%a:~-3%"=="%%a" echo goto:next & pause
```

Comment: I have just tried the code, but I am a little confused. The folder can either have ESP, GBR or SPE at the end of it, but never all 3, e.g, `Folder - ESP, Folder - GBR, Folder - SPE`. I have tried the above code however it does not work as a folder with `- GBR` is still processed.

Comment: I don't know what you expect the code to do now.  See my edited code above with an example that works.

Comment: I have tried however if the folder is `test - GBR` the folder is processed. So it does not SKIP the process. I have published the entire code.

Comment: @foidrive I have tried this, `echo Most recent video created: &echo. & echo."%a%"
if /i "%a:~-3%"=="ESP" ( 
goto:next 
) else if /i "%a:~-3%"=="GBR" 
(
goto:next 
) else if /i "%a:~-3%"=="SPE"
(
goto:next
)
else
)
echo THis works 
)` No joy