# Conditional Batch Login File

Tags: batch-file, login-script

Is it possible to use If...Else statements in a windows batch file?

I was considering changing the windows login script in a similar way to this:

```
If username=user1, user2, user3 (
     *instructions here*
     )
Else If username=user4, user5, user6 (
     *instructions here*
     )
Else (
     *instructions here*
     )
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use if-else. `AND` and `OR` is a little bit tricky. Look at the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438511/if-or-if-in-a-windows-batch-file) and [here](ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Answer (score 3):

A good and robust way to do it:

```
@echo off

set $L1=user1,user2,user3
set $L2=user4,user5,user6

for %%a in (%$L1%) do if /i "%username%"=="%%a" goto Case1
for %%a in (%$L2%) do if /i "%username%"=="%%a" goto Case2
goto Nocase

:Case1
echo User 1-3
exit /b

:Case2
echo User 4-6
exit /b

:Nocase
echo NO CASE
```

You can expand it easily with other lists ($L3, $L4, ...).

Comment: @Mofi - Changing format of `goto` statements is OK, but original syntax of `goto:Case1` works perfectly well, though it does look a bit odd. The other edits are all good.

Comment: @dbenham - I executed the original batch file with `goto:Case1` and therefore knew that this also worked. But syntactically it is not 100% correct. It works because cmd.exe interprets the colon as delimiter character or ignores it because of being an invalid character for a label with the exception of `goto :EOF`, see [goto](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/goto.mspx) description (also on referenced related page for `if`). The code examples on Stack Overflow should be as "beautiful" as possible and not quirks code, especially on good code as here.

Answer (score 1):

sachadee has a good answer that uses GOTO. But it is possible to easily achieve the result without GOTO.

An attempt is made to replace the current user name with nothing within a list variable. If the result is different than the original, then the current user must be in the list. Note the leading and trailing commas in the lists. They are important.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "list1=,user1,user2,user3,"
set "list2=,user4,user5,user6,"
if "!list1:,%username%,=!" neq "!list1!" (
  echo code for user 1-3 here
) else if "!list2:,%username%,=!" neq "!list1!" (
  echo code for users 4-6 here
) else (
  echo code for all others here
)
```