# window cmd if statement, how to make different file according different cases?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, windows-scripting

```
if 0 NEQ 0 cd.>done.txt
if 11 EQU 0 cd.>fail.txt
pause
```

This is a bat file,when i run it,both done.txt and fail.txt generated.But I want only generate done.txt. It means I want generate different file according different case.What shall i do?

Comment: with your shown code, none of the files is generated.

Comment: @Stephan I`m sorry,there is something wrong when I paste my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@echo off
set var=11
set var2=0
if %var%==%var2% (
  echo %var% is %var2% >done.txt
) else (
  echo %var% is not %var2% >fail.txt)
pause
```

You can change the value of `var` and `var2` to see the different files.

So by using your scenario we can replace the echo strings with:

```
@echo off
set var=11
set var2=0
if %var%==%var2% (
  cd. >done.txt
) else (
  cd. >fail.txt)
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to do an OR statement, so that if either result is true the output is piped to done.txt. Is that right?

Have a look at the answer here for a neat solution: [IF... OR IF... in a windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438511/if-or-if-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: If some operation success,I only want to generate done.txt.If the operation fails,then I only want to generate fail.txt.what I don`t understand is 11 is not equals 0,why the statement "cd.>fail.txt" is executed

Comment: @user6630815: double check. It isn't.