# Batch If x or y statement problems

Tags: batch-file

```
if %input%==0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || "A" || "B" || "C" || "D" || "E" || "F" goto Text
```

I tried using  this line so that if %input% was 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E, or F it would goto :Text but it just closes the prompt (there's nothing after it).  How can i get this to do what i want it to do?

Comment: `|` is a reserved character meaning run the next command if previously failed. Don't use reserved characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IF... OR IF... in a windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438511/if-or-if-in-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Where in the help file does it show that syntax for the IF command?

Comment: I'd be more interested in finding _any_ language that lets you do that.

Comment: Simple: `set "options=0123456789ABCDEF"` and  `if "!options:%input%=!" neq "%options%" goto Text`. Simpler: use `choice /C 0123456789ABCDEF` to get the input...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated bellow your post comments or by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28891643/8667430) - Double Pipes; `||` executes the following command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0 (Or in other terms, fails).

An easy way to fix this post, is to use an `for loop` to go through multiple variables and compare them in an `IF` statement to your string. If there is a match, it will use the `GOTO` command listed in your post. If no match was found it will end the loop. Keep in mind an `ELSE` command can be used to redirect a no match result. `if "%input%"==%%A (goto Text) ELSE (goto NoMatchesFound)`.

```
for %%A in ("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F") do (if "%input%"==%%A (goto Text))
```