# IF EXIST .. & IF EXIST ... (ECHO ...) ELSE (ECHO ..) doesnt work for me

Tags: batch-file

AFAIK the working solution was kindly shared by TripeHound .... **If you want to test both files exist, you want `IF EXIST D:\ann.PDF IF EXIST D:\file.html ECHO` ... The conditional command of the first IF is the second IF and if that is also true, the ECHO is executed. –**  *TripeHound*

The answers accepted here [How to run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd) are not working for me.

When I have only one 'IF EXIST ..' there is no problem. When I try having two on the same line using &, (or && in .bat) the batch file crashes or the CLI post an error **""** *& was unexpected at this time* **""**

This is the code I tried and the (very consistent) results

```
 C:\Windows\system32> IF EXIST D:\file.html  (ECHO this is good) ELSE (ECHO this really sucks)
 this is good
```

response is "this is good" because both of the test files (ann.PDF and file.html) exist

```
  C:\Windows\system32> IF EXIST D:\ann.PDF & IF EXIST D:\file.html (ECHO this is good) ELSE (ECHO this really sucks)
    & was unexpected at this time.
```

I haven't got a clue why the ***'unexpected'*** error is given.. any productive suggestions are welcome  ... using Windows 7 x64 but solution has to also work on XP sp3 .... TVMIA !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an OR in an IF statement WinXP Batch Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273433/using-an-or-in-an-if-statement-winxp-batch-script)

Comment: @Dawa Law  @trigger Thanks !. I looked at that and dont think it applies ... try experiment: put the following in standard windows cmd console `IF EXIST D:\ann.PDF  &  IF EXIST D:\file.html  (ECHO passes) ELSE (ECHO fails)` I anticipate you will see a response **fails** bcz you dont have the files in your D partition, and I expect  **passes**  bcz files exist. The error  ` & was unexpected at this time` . I think I would see if there was an open bracket anywhere before ` & ` but that is **not** the case. `IF EXIST D:\ann.PDF (ECHO passes) ELSE (ECHO fails)` by itself **passes**

Comment: If you want to test both files exist, you want `IF EXIST D:\ann.PDF IF EXIST D:\file.html ECHO ...`  The conditional command of the first `IF` is the second `IF` and if that is also true, the `ECHO` is executed.

Comment: @TripeHound  That WORKS, and I am amazed that it does considering the answered question in the link included in my question copy. I am pleased that it works, and can you post a link where the info was located (if available), to help out anyone that gets directed to this thread?!

Comment: I told you the same thing 19 hours ago. You seem stupid.

Answer (score 0):

```
If exist <filename> <command>
```

You don't have a command on the one's that don't work. `&`, `&&`, and `||` work on error levels from a command. `If Exist` doesn't.

```
C:\Users\David Candy>type %windir%\winhelp.ini  && (echo. & echo found) || echo
not found
[Files]
Serenity.hlp=C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop

found
```

and

```
C:\Users\David Candy>type %windir%\winhelp1.ini  && (echo. & echo found) || echo
 not found
The system cannot find the file specified.
not found
```

Comment: **I am sorry.** Had far too many examples and confused the question. I have simplified the question content to minimum needed, to avoid confusion.

Comment: `If exist c:\somefile if exist someotherfile`. `If` is a command so can appear in the command part of another `if`.